# Adding \ in sprintf for C

Tags: c

I am trying to add the \ in C with:
`sprintf("trying to add \ in this print");` I have tried to lookup and find this and I cannot seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the double backslash: `sprintf("trying to add \\ in this print");`?

Comment: I didn't try it no, I went to go and try it and it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Nocturnal Look up a list of all the escape characters, because it seems like you don't know them all yet. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C This should be useful

Comment: But preferably from a real documentation site like https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape